# Is a null hypothesis which requires a minimum performance on a predictive model testable?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, statistical-significance, research-design

Given: A null hypothesis which requires a specific performance, which can be directly measured, is testable.

Is a null hypothesis which requires a specific performance on a predictive model testable?

(This class of predictive models is models utilizing data mining strategies. I know this is a broad class, so we can restrict this to the example below.)

For example, can a null hypothesis be written which requires that a logistic regression model that predicts churn will predict at least one churn with at least 85% confidence?  The specific construction of the logistic model is predefined, as are the input variables (in the hypotheses).

Or, is it only possible to test for a significant relationship between the independent variables and the dependent variable, and the details must be left to the discussion of the results?

The point is, can a null hypotheses, which is the foundation of a major class of research, require performance on a predictive model that is higher than merely establishing statistical significance?

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question but you can test the statistical significance of various predictive statistics for models such as AUC. For example, you have test that the AUC is different than 0 or 0.5 (or any other value you choose).

Comment: The question is whether a null hypothesis can require a specific, minimum, AUC.  With hypothesis testing, there is a confidence test (typically 0.05).  A null hypothesis gets rejected (or not), and the alternative hypothesis is accepted if the null hypothesis is rejected.  -- Can you say the predictive model's prediction of 0.75 is valid within 0.05?

Comment: Yes. For example if your minimum acceptable AUC= 0.75, you could formulate the hypothesis test so H0: AUC <= 0.75 and Ha: AUC > 0.75.

Comment: @Great38 - but how do you test the significance of the AUC result?

Comment: It can be done in SAS using the ROC statement in proc logisitic. I'm not sure in R, but I bet there is a way. I believe the method SAS uses is explained here: E.R. DeLong, D.M. DeLong, and D.L. Clarke-Pearson (1988), "Comparing the Areas Under Two or More Correlated Receiver Operating Characteristic Curves: A Nonparametric Approach," Biometrics, 44, 837-845.